# Setting the Identity/Principal from a MessageInspector in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication

I am developing a WCF service that receives the user's credentials in the SOAP header. These credentials are read on the server side using a MessageInspector. So far so good.

I want to set the Thread.CurrentPrincipal to a custom principal (CustomPrincipal), but when I do this from the MessageInspector, it gets overridden by the time the service is invoked. When is the best time to set the principal? Also what is the best way to pass the principal, identity or credentials from the inspector to that location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rory has a post that describes a solution to this problem.
http://www.neovolve.com/2008/04/07/wcf-security-getting-the-password-of-the-user/

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, to do this you need to set the principal permission mode to "custom" and use an authorization policy, [like so](http://www.leastprivilege.com/CustomPrincipalsAndWCF.aspx). As far as I know, the call to `IAuthorizationPolicy.Evaluate` is the only place it is expecting you to set a principal, and when I tried this *without* using `IAuthorizationPolicy` it discarded my principal (which makes sense, since there is no guarantee that WCF will use the same thread at each point in the pipeline).

Comment: Where does the IIdentity get set into the EvaluationContext? I need to figure out what credentials are passed in the header.

Comment: @Robert - I'm sorry, it has been literally years since I last did this; I don't remember.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, if you are hosting the WCF services within IIS, you can enable the aspnetcompatibility behavior for  your service. In that case you can set HttpConext.Current.User to the user you just authenticated within your message inspector.